# uWSGI module found when invoked on the command line but not when invoked using emperor

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

I have a python wsgi application which I am running under uWSGI.

When I try to run the same application using emperor I get an error -

```
ImportError: No module named app_thing
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

If I run uWSGI directly specifying the same config file that emperor is using it finds the module and the application works.

uWSGI config file below.

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
workers = 1
force-cwd = /home/user/py
module = app_thing:application
protocol = http
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: force-cwd looks a bit strange, maybe you want chdir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out the fix involved setting the file rather than the module and also adding the dir to the python path in the uWSGI config. Final config ended up as

```
    [uwsgi]
    socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
    workers = 1
    force-cwd = /home/py
    file = /home/py/app_thing.py
    pythonpath = /home/py
```